# How do I integrate Perfidies (Browser plug-in vulnerability scanner) into my website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, security, plugins, browser

[Perfidies](https://github.com/ozten/Perfidies-of-the-Web/tree) / [Plugindir](https://github.com/lmorchard/plugindir) is the client to [Mozilla's plugin vulnerability database](https://wiki.mozilla.org/PFS2#Codebases).  I think a variant of this is used here on [this site geared for end users](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/).

I would like to redirect any browser that is using an old version of Java, Silverlight, Flash, etc to a "quarantine" page asking them to upgrade their browser before they are permitted to log in.

- What technical changes do I need to make to accomplish this?
- What Perfidies specific javascript objects must I become aware of?
- Are there any deployment concerns or modifications I should make?

...
...

Comment: I fear that question is probably out of scope for here: you have already decided on the security control you want to implement (decided badly, but that's not relevant to your question :-) and now just need to sort out the tedious implmentation details. One of the Stack Exchanges for web developers will be able to give you much better help.

Comment: @GrahamHill's comment is partially correct. Implementation details, and how to code it, might be better on e.g. SO (assuming enough popularity that there are enough other programmers that have implemented it). However, your third bullet is definitely on topic here - other concerns to take into account.

Comment: I flagged it to move to Stackoverflow.  @GrahamHill If you question my use of this, please [comment on this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/12039/396).  I'd be interested in hearing your thoughts

Comment: @makerofthings7 moving. Though I think there is still room to ask the last bullet here, as it *is* a security feature...

Comment: @makerofthings7 you don't provide any details needed to answer your first and third question... it is really unclear what exactly you want to achieve and what sort of application you want to integrate this into (webserver, OS etc.) ?

Comment: @Yahia - I thought this is mostly client side, so I didn't mention it.  I'm using ASP.NET / MVC

Comment: @makerofthings7 you still didn't say what your goal is exactly... BTW the technique used to achieve this functionality relies on JSONP which is by itself a potential security risk... so: what exactly is your goal ?

Comment: @makerofthings7 the security risk through JSONP could be reduced by installing the vulenrability DB on your server which would avoid cross-site-JSON-access... another option would be to create a "proxy" on your server which acts as the "secure" middle-man between your clients and the vulnerability DB...

Comment: @Yahia I like the proxy idea.  It also allows for centralized (trusted) reporting.  I'm still stuck at (and hoping for guidance in) slicing up the code in a way that is compatible with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @makerofthings7 you don't need to change the code IMO (except for communicating to your proxy instead of mozilla)... I would just implement this as a "static gatekeeper page upfront" which redirects to your APS.NET/MVC application if results are positive...

Comment: What is your budget?
http://www.browserhawk.com/products/bhawk/ Information here about both above and brewing your own:
http://forums.asp.net/t/414450.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

You should provide some more context to your question. I will try to help you though suggesting a way to do this.

You mentioned you want to disallow users to login, so I think the best way to do this is putting the validation code in the login page as a javascript include. Keep in mind since the script is executed on the client, there is no guarantee that it will really execute and an expert user can circumvent your "protection" by e.g. disabling scripting. But if you are in an intranet and generally trust your users, it shouldn't be a big problem.

To learn how to use Perfidies, I recommend you looking at the following file which you should be able to change to your needs (not tested!).
https://github.com/ozten/Perfidies-of-the-Web/blob/master/plugincheck_ui.js

The main function to call seems to be `Pfs.findPluginInfos(Pfs.UI.navInfo, browserPlugins, incrementalCallbackFn, finishedCallbackFn)`. In the `incrementalCallbackFn` you get all vulnerable plugins. If there exists one, you can redirect the browser to your page.

See the referenced page to see how to fill the other function-parameters.

Regarding deployment I would allow some way to skip this verification, because there are always cases in which you want to allow exceptional access. If your boss needs a report in 5 minutes you don't want to tell him that he has to update his java version first, just because there was an update yesterday which probably isn't even exploited yet.

So maybe show a big red warning for users trying to access the page, but give them a way to ignore the warning if they choose to...